# New version of h2o in R still produces additional row when calling as.h2o on column names with special characters

Tags: r, h2o

I am still having the problem outlined by another user in this question: [as.h2o produces additional row when column names contain special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463961/as-h2o-produces-additional-row-when-column-names-contain-special-characters)

Currently, h2o is on version 3.18.0.11, and it looks like this issue has only been resolved up to 3.18.0.08. I have tried to downgrade the installation of h2o on my computer but I got an error when trying to run this.

Is there any way to circumvent this problem? Might it work on a different computer (if I can get access to one)?

**Edit**: I am using RStudio on a laptop running Windows 7, and the version of R is 3.4.4.

**Edit**: Here is an example of what causes this bug.

```
df <- replicate(3, rnorm(5))
colnames(df) <- c("–coliform", "‘’append", "dog")
df.h2o <- as.h2o(df)
```

The output from this code is:

```
Ã¯Â¿Â½coliform Ã¯Â¿Â½Ã¯Â¿Â½append         dog
1            NaN                NaN         NaN
2      1.3680317         0.33229608 -0.82884927
3     -0.8913680         2.79798207  0.21854663
4     -0.1836785        -0.07519385  1.44215138
5      1.6093652         0.79405964  0.07038501
6     -0.5938197        -0.10297580  0.36824972
```

Comment: can you provide your environment information (i.e. version of R, type of OS).

Comment: @Lauren added to my question.

Comment: can you post an example code snippet like this one `df <- replicate(3, rnorm(5)) ; colnames(df) <- c('A', 'B', 'Č'), df_h2o <- as.h2o(df)`. Thanks!

Comment: @Lauren added it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested out the special character issue from the post you specified, using the corresponding [Jira Ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5267) code snippet. I was **not** able to reproduce an issue; the rendering of the character is correct, for both version 3.18.0.11 and 3.18.0.08. I used Mac OS X El Capitan, with R version 3.4.2.

To install version 3.18.0.11, first make sure h2o isn't running somewhere then run the following code found in h2o's download instructions

```
# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

Next, we download packages that H2O depends on.
pkgs <- c("RCurl","jsonlite")
for (pkg in pkgs) {
  if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
}

# Now we download, install and initialize the H2O package for R.
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/11/R")
```

If you want to downgrade to 3.18.08, shutdown h2o, shutdown R and then rerun the above but specify the link for 3.18.08 `install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/8/R").`

Comment: Could you try using one or both of these special characters:  "–" and "‘’" in your column names?